# Undefined Reference error for Constructor using Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm working on a student project to create a pair of robots that tell the time by climbing up and down, using Arduinos (including the Arduino IDE). Part of this project includes a simple ML AI that will auto adjust the speed of the robot to make sure it reaches the top at the correct rate. I've made a library to provide the necessary variables and functions to perform this task.

In an earlier version of this library (which compiled just fine), there was only one constructor that used an array to store the data, such that the array length is always a specific length. In the next version, another constructor is being made to allow for an array length specified upon construction, as the Arduino IDE does not allow for the usage of the vector library. However, when attempting to compile the source code with the setup and loop functions, an undefined reference error to the constructor being used. Ignoring the irrelevant code, my codebase looks like

## Main program

```
#include "libraries/SpeedCorrector/SpeedCorrector.h"

const uint8_t MAX_HOURS = 12; //12 hour clock
const uint32_t CORRECT_TIME = MAX_HOURS*60*60*1000; //Num of milliseconds in 12 hours
const uint16_t INITIAL_PWM = 300; //dummy initial PWM value for testing

uint32_t climbTime;
uint16_t currentPwm;
uint16_t tempPwm;
bool photoInterruptMet = false;

SpeedCorrector speedCorrector(INITIAL_PWM, CORRECT_TIME);
```

## SpeedCorrector.h

```
#ifndef SpeedCorrector_h
#define SpeedCorrector_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class SpeedCorrector {
    public:
        const static uint8_t MAX_NUM_OF_PWM = 10; //default value
        const static uint16_t MOTOR_SLIP_CORRECTION = 10; //default value

        SpeedCorrector(uint16_t initialPwm, uint32_t inCorrectTime);
        SpeedCorrector(uint16_t initialPwm, uint32_t inCorrectTime, uint8_t inMaxNumOfPwm, uint8_t inMotorSlipCorrection);
    private:
        uint8_t pwmIndex;
        uint8_t maxNumOfPwms;
        bool correctedPwmsFull;
        uint32_t correctTime;
        uint8_t motorSlipCorrection;
};

#endif
```

## SpeedCorrector.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SpeedCorrector.h"

SpeedCorrector::SpeedCorrector(uint16_t initialPwm, uint32_t inCorrectTime) {
    pwmIndex = 0;
    maxNumOfPwms = MAX_NUM_OF_PWMS;
    uint16_t correctedPwms[maxNumOfPwms];
    correctedPwmsFull = false;
    correctedPwms[0] = initialPwm;
    correctTime = inCorrectTime;
    motorSlipCorrection = MOTOR_SLIP_CORRECTION;
}

SpeedCorrector::SpeedCorrector(uint16_t initialPwm, uint32_t inCorrectTime, 
                          uint8_t inMaxNumOfPwms, uint8_t inMotorSlipCorrection) {
  pwmIndex = 0;
  maxNumOfPwms = inMaxNumOfPwms
  uint16_t correctedPwms[maxNumOfPwms];
  correctedPwmsFull = false;
  correctedPwms[0] = initialPwm;
  correctTime = inCorrectTime;
  motorSlipCorrection = inMotorSlipCorrection;
}
```

Unfortunately, I've had to declare the array in the constructor to allow for the length to be specified upon construction.

I've attempted to comment out the array to see if I get different error messages, but to no avail. I've also moved the library into a different directory and I get a `no such file or directory` error, so it's definitely detecting the library.

The error complains on the construction of the SpeedCorrector in the main program, stating

```
undefined reference to `SpeedCorrector::SpeedCorrector(unsigned int, unsigned long)'
```

I got the instruction on how to make the library from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

Comment: Do you really compile `SpeedCorrector.cpp` file?

Comment: Why does your `SpeedCorrector.h` include itself?

Comment: @tkausl Because those are part of the official instructions from the Arduino website. See the edit.

Comment: @tkausl Upon another read, you're concern is warranted. I must of misread the website. I've edited my post to fix this.

Comment: As pointed out  by vahancho this function does not seem to exist at link time. Please insert a syntax error in `SpeedCorrector.cpp` and try to recompile/link.

Comment: in .ino `#include <SpeedCorrector.h>`

Comment: @prog-fh What does this accomplish? I've inserted a syntax error and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Juraj That only works if I've installed the library into the Arduino IDE. Please see the link at the bottom of my question.

Comment: from the path I expected that you have the file in `libraries` subfolder of your sketches folder. then the syntax with <> is right

Comment: If an arbitrary syntax error introduced in your `SpeedCorrector.cpp` is not reported when you build your binary, that means this source file is not even considered during the build process (as if it simply didn't exist). Thus the problem does probably not stand in something you wrote in your source code, but rather in the way your source files are organised (in the correct folder? isn't there an invisible character in its name? ...)

Comment: @Juraj are you sure? I tried this myself, but the Arduino IDE returns a compile-time error message stating it could not find the file nor the directory. Additionally, the official instructions state that the library must be installed via the Arduino IDE itself (see the link at the bottom of my question).

Comment: 100% sure. the IDE doesn't know how the library was put there. if you have a folder SpeedCorrector in libraries and a .h and .cpp in that folder, then you have a library there

Comment: @prog-fh I tried moving the library into a different directory without changing the #include line in my main program and the Arduino IDE gave a different error message, stating that it couldn't find the library. Ergo, it's definitely detecting the library. I've even copied and pasted the folder names just to make sure there are no spelling errors, but I'm still getting the undefined reference error.

Comment: You are declaring a local array `correctedPwms` that you can never access again! What's the point of that? (And dynamically sized arrays are not valid in C++ anyway.)

Comment: @TonyK the point is to allow for the creation of an array whose size can be specified upon construction of the SpeedCorrector object, as opposed to being stuck to one specific size for all SpeedCorrector objects or having multiple copies of the library for each desired size. Unfortunately, the Arduino IDE does not allow for the usage of C++ vectors, so I'm stuck with arrays. You're point is valid though, I forgot that the array would be deleted quickly after being declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to File/Preferences in the arduino IDE, the default SketchBook location is `/home/user_name/Arduino`.

So the `SpeedCorrector.h` and `SpeedCorrector.cpp` files should be placed in `/home/user_name/Arduino/libraries/SpeedCorrector`, not in a subdirectory of the one where stands the main (`.ino`) program.

As stated by Juraj in the comments, the main program (`.ino`) should then use `#include <SpeedCorrector.h>`, without any full path to the header file.